# mysqldump got errors, Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql

When i am use mysqldump -uroot -p xxx > xxx.sql, i got some errors, 'mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `GAMES` at row: 20826'.

Then i checked the mysql error logs, i found the errors below. I search lots of sites in google but got nothing.

Anyone who can help me with this, thank you!

```
2018-07-31 00:21:04 0x7fb3cc0ab700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140410199127808 in file btr0pcur.cc line 452
InnoDB: Failing assertion: page_is_comp(next_page) == page_is_comp(page)
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
16:21:04 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 76387 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fb3a4012330
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fb3cc0aae70 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xe907ab]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x489)[0x789b49]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7fb3e79ca390]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7fb3e6d83428]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7fb3e6d8502a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x75f3e0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z26btr_pcur_move_to_next_pageP10btr_pcur_tP5mtr_t+0x1c8)[0x114e6f8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x75cfbf]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15row_search_mvccPh15page_cur_mode_tP14row_prebuilt_tmm+0x11e5)[0x1099745]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN11ha_innobase13general_fetchEPhjj+0x6a)[0xf87a7a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler11ha_rnd_nextEPh+0xfc)[0x7d961c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13rr_sequentialP11READ_RECORD+0x35)[0xbb3445]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10sub_selectP4JOINP7QEP_TABb+0x13e)[0xc23ffe]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x3c8)[0xc1cd18]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12handle_queryP3THDP3LEXP12Query_resultyy+0x233)[0xc8e753]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7533a8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x492e)[0xc506ee]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDP12Parser_state+0x3ad)[0xc52b3d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_commandP3THDPK8COM_DATA19enum_server_command+0x102a)[0xc53c7a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x1c7)[0xc55137]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_connection+0x288)[0xd16788]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x1b4)[0xec9294]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7fb3e79c06ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fb3e6e5541d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7fb3a404ae60): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 4
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2018-07-30T16:21:04.660409Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2018-07-30T16:21:04.660458Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2018-07-30T16:21:04.840982Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-07-30T16:21:04.842849Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 26568 ...
2018-07-30T16:21:04.847280Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2018-07-30T16:21:04.847312Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-07-30T16:21:04.847319Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-07-30T16:21:04.847324Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-07-30T16:21:04.847331Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2018-07-30T16:21:04.847336Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-07-30T16:21:04.847618Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-07-30T16:21:04.847762Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-07-30T16:21:04.849397Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-07-30T16:21:04.857825Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-07-30T16:21:04.860275Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-07-30T16:21:04.872370Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-07-30T16:21:04.892980Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 5386460686
2018-07-30T16:21:04.893001Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 5386460695
2018-07-30T16:21:04.893008Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2018-07-30T16:21:04.893013Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2018-07-30T16:21:05.008438Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2018-07-30T16:21:05.008468Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-07-30T16:21:05.008507Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-07-30T16:21:05.103402Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-07-30T16:21:05.104128Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-07-30T16:21:05.104147Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-07-30T16:21:05.105002Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.22 started; log sequence number 5386460695
2018-07-30T16:21:05.105371Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-07-30T16:21:05.106533Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-07-30T16:21:05.112425Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2018-07-30T16:21:05.112600Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-07-30T16:21:05.114984Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2018-07-30T16:21:05.115009Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2018-07-30T16:21:05.115029Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2018-07-30T16:21:05.121314Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2018-07-30T16:21:05.122659Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180731  0:21:05
2018-07-30T16:21:05.122807Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2018-07-30T16:21:05.661985Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: First, please work on your question asking skills and take the tour before asking a question. Second you seem to have more serious problems than getting timeout error during query as per the last line of your log file ` Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. Finally, please share more info including the client you're using to run a query on the server (JDBC-used code piece, Mysql clients (workbench, heidiSQL etc.) and the query string you're running.

Comment: @dashboard I have edited the question, thank you man

Comment: Okay, if these are the last lines of the log file then first we have to fix `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` . That means you can't log in to the server using the user named `root` and connection type of PID file (server address being localhost). Could there be a password to the user `root` ?

Comment: It's saying "using password: NO" because of the space after -p. The password needs to come directly after the flag, so like -pxxx.

Comment: @Anch0rman No, don't type password in command, when you enter 'mysqldump -uroot -p', it will ask you to enter the password :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf or my.ini [mysqld] section

```
SELECT @@thread_cache_size;  # will give you current setting
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;  # will give you current setting
```

Multiply each by 1.3 and set with

```
SET GLOBAL thread_cache_size=<calculated-size>;  # use rounded UP whole numbers
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=<calculated-size>;
```

or if you have an OLD VERSION of MySQL, you must change in your 
my.cnf or my.ini, shutdown/restart.

Let us know how it goes, please.

For additional assistance, view profile, Network Profile, for contact info including Skype ID.  Thanks

Comment: My Mysql version is 'mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper'.
I have followed your suggestion, it's not work for me.
check this http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/006wgEZHgy1ftu1vhrth0j30l60lc0w8.jpg